# Problems with counting a number of rows in SQL and grouping them

Tags: sql

I am having a problem with trying to count a number of rows and then grouping them in SQL.

I have used the SELECT query below to create a table.

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, bed_no
FROM ward, bed
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no

ward_no  bed_no

w1         1
w1         2
w1         3
w1         4
w2         5
w2         6
w2         7
w3         8
w3         9
w3         10
w4         11
```

What I am trying to do is create a table where it shows each ward no ie w1 and a field showing how many fields is in it.

```
eg. w1   3
    w2   3
    w3   3
```

I have tried the COUNT & GROUP BY fields like so...

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, bed_no
FROM ward, bed
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
AND COUNT (bed_no) AS beds_in_ward
GROUP BY ward_no;
```

but with no joy, any advice would be fully appreciated

Comment: For future reference, it helps if you include the actual error message or expected/actual output in your question so we can see what the nature of the problem is. "no joy" doesn't really give enough information.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, COUNT(*) AS beds_in_ward
    FROM ward
        INNER JOIN bed
            ON ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
    GROUP BY ward.ward_no
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have the SQL syntax wrong. Try this.

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, count(bed.Bed_No)
FROM ward INNER JOIN bed (on  ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no)
GROUP BY ward_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. maybe you want the number of beds in each ward?
and maybe your example is not exactly correct - there should be 4 in w1.

if so then try this:

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, count(bed_no)
FROM ward, bed
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
group by ward.ward_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers above are correct. Another way (in SQLServer) is to use the partition function:

```
SELECT distinct ward.ward_no, 
  count(1) over (partition by ward_no) as c
FROM ward, bed
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
```

Which seems stupid, unless you happen to have multiple types of grouping in one statement or you want to include columns that aren't in your group by statement:

```
SELECT distinct ward.ward_no, 
  ward.whatever_column_you_want, 
  bed.whatever_column_you_want, 
  count(1) over (partition by ward_no) as c
FROM ward, bed
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
```

OR

```
SELECT distinct ward.ward_no, 
  some_other_columns,
  count(1) over (partition by ward_no) as bed_count,
  count(1) over (partition by some_other_columns) as other_count
FROM ward, bed
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
```