# SQL and grouping & count problems

Tags: sql

I am having a problem with trying to count a number of rows and then grouping them in SQL.

I have used the SELECT query below to create a table.

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, bed_no   
FROM ward, bed 
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
```

.

```
ward_no     bed_no

w1         1.
w1         2.
w1         3.    
w1         4.    
w2         5.    
w2         6.    
w2         7.   
w3         8.    
w3         9.    
w3         10.   
w4         11.
```

What I am trying to do is create a table where it shows each ward no ie w1 and a field showing how many fields is in it.

eg.

```
w1   3.
w2   3.
w3   3
```

I have tried the COUNT & GROUP BY fields like so...

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, bed_no
FROM ward, bed  
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no  
AND COUNT (bed_no) AS beds_in_ward  
GROUP BY ward_no;
```

but with no joy, any advice would be fully appreciated

Comment: Don't understand where your desired results come from. Shouldn't it be `(w1,4),(w2,3),(w3,3),(w4,1)` from your sample data?

Comment: @Andrew Rose, did you just ask this twice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with counting a number of rows in SQL and grouping them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397851/problems-with-counting-a-number-of-rows-in-sql-and-grouping-them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your `COUNT()` in the wrong place

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, COUNT (bed_no) AS beds_in_ward
FROM ward
INNER JOIN bed
ON ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
GROUP BY ward_no;
```

I also updated the query to use `JOIN` instead of the `','` between your tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sorry for the initial messy message it is my first time asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ward.ward_no, count(*) as no_of_beds
FROM 
    ward, bed
WHERE 
    ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
GROUP BY 
    ward_no;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sorry for the initial messy message it is my first time asking a question - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, COUNT (bed_no) AS beds_in_ward
FROM ward, bed
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
GROUP BY ward_no;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sorry for the initial messy message it is my first time asking a question - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ward.ward_no, count(bed_no)
FROM ward, bed
WHERE ward.ward_no = bed.ward_no
GROUP BY ward.ward_no
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sorry for the initial messy message it is my first time asking a question - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to do here, but i guess it is this:

```
SELECT 
w.ward_no, count(bed_no) 
FROM ward w
inner join bed b on b.ward_no = w.ward_no
GROUP BY w.ward_no;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sorry for the initial messy message it is my first time asking a question - Thanks again.